# Why does threading.Thread operate synchronously by blocking execution in python 2.5?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.5

I am limited to python2.5, and I thought that threading.Thread was asynchronous.  I run: python t.py and the script does not return to the shell until 3 seconds have gone by, which means its blocking. Why is it blocking?

My Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading,time

def doit():
  time.sleep(3)
  print "DONE"

thr = threading.Thread(target=doit, args=(), kwargs={})
thr.start() # will run "foo"
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "synchronous" in this context? What behavior are you expecting to see? What are you actually seeing?

Comment: good question, threading always bug for me on python 2.x. It works fine in python 3. edit : tryed in python 2.7.6 and it works now, so probably a bug in an earlier version of python

Comment: @dano I added more information to the question. Please re-read, and thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, threads in Python are non-daemonic. A Python application [will not exit](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#thread-objects) until the all non-daemon threads have completed, so in your case it won't exit until `doit` has finished. If you want to script to exit immediately upon reaching the end of the main thread, you need to make the thread a daemon, by setting the [`daemon` attribute](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) prior to starting the thread:

```
thr = threading.Thread(target=doit, args=(), kwargs={})
thr.daemon = True
thr.start()
```

Comment: Good. Now where does stdout go in deamon mode?

Comment: @hunterp: `daemon` threads will not keep running after Python exits.

Comment: @hunterp stdout is shared across all threads. When the Python process exits, it's closed.

Answer (score 1):

Threading in Python is "kind-of" asynchronous.  What does this mean?

- Only one thread can be running Python code at one time
- threads that are Python code and CPU intensive will not benefit

Your issue seems to be that you think a Python thread should keep running after Python itself quits -- that's not how it works.  If you do make a thread a `daemon` then when Python quits those threads just die, instantly -- no cleanup, no error recovery, just dead.

If you want to actually make a daemon process, something that keeps running in the background after the main application exits, you want to look at `os.fork()`.  If you want to do it the easier way, you can try my daemon library, [pandaemonium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandaemonium)